# Unable to start container using kubectl

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm, minikube

I am learning kubernetes and using minikube to create single node cluster in my ubuntu machine. In my ubuntu machine Oracle Virtualbox is also installed. As I run

```
$ minikube start

Starting local Kubernetes v1.6.4 cluster...
...

$ cat ~/.kube/config

apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /root/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://192.168.99.100:8443
  name: minikube
... 

$ kubectl run hello-minikube --image=gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4 --port=8000

error: failed to discover supported resources: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api: Service Unavailable
```

I am not getting that what is causing this error. Is there some place we can check for logs. I cannot use kubectl logs as it requires container to mention which is not creating at all. Please provide any possible solution to problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can debug using these steps:

1. `kubectl` talks to `kube-apiserver` at port 8443 to do its thing. Try `curl -k https://192.168.99.100:8443` and see if there's a positive response. If this fails, it means `kube-apiserver` isn't running at all. You can try restarting the VM or rebuilding minikube to see if it comes up properly the 2nd time round.
2. You can also debug the VM directly if you feel brave. In this case, get a shell on the VM spun up by minikube. Run `docker ps | grep apiserver` to check if the `kube-apiserver` pod is running. Also try `ps aux | grep apiserver` to check if it's run natively. If both don't turn up results, check the logs using `journalctl -xef`.

Comment: Step 1 worked for me. when i start my macMini docker is always running but minikube i need to start every time. As it was not running , command "curl -k https://192.168.99.100:8443" is failing. so i started minikube using "minikube start" command.